# Pandas: Split Colum into n new columns on separator

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

I’ve a Dataframe where in some columns there are multiple values, always separated by `,`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['', 'mariachi', 'mexico, united states'],
                   ['', 'jazz, rap', 'united states'],
                   ['', '', 'spain'],
                   ['jimi hendrix, john lennon', 'rock', ''],
                   ['spirit', '', 'united states'],
                   ['', 'latin', 'united states'],
                   ['', '', ''],
                   ['speak', '', 'mexico, united states']], 
                   columns=['Musician', 'Genre', 'Country'])


                        Musician          Genre                   Country
   1                         NaN       mariachi     mexico, united states
   2                         NaN      jazz, rap             united states
   3                         NaN            NaN                     spain
   4   jimi hendrix, john lennon           rock                       NaN
   5                      spirit            NaN             united states
   6                         NaN          latin             united states
   7                         NaN            NaN                       NaN
   8                       speak            NaN     mexico, united states
```

How can I split the columns to `n` columns with each containing only one variable?

e.g.:

```
          Musician       Musician2          Genre      Genre2          Country         Country2
   1           NaN             NaN       mariachi         NaN           mexico    united states
   2           NaN             NaN           jazz         rap    united states              NaN
   3           NaN             NaN            NaN         NaN            spain              NaN
   4  jimi hendrix     john lennon           rock         NaN              NaN              NaN
   5        spirit             NaN            NaN         NaN    united states              NaN
   6           NaN             NaN          latin         NaN    united states              NaN
   7           NaN             NaN            NaN         NaN              NaN              NaN
   8         speak             NaN            NaN         NaN           mexico    united states
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `list comprehension` with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), then remove `Multiindex` in columns by `map` and `join` and last [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) all empty `strings` and `None` to `NaN`:

```
cols = ['Musician','Genre','Country']
df = pd.concat([df[x].str.split(',', expand=True) for x in cols], axis=1, keys=df.columns)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: '_'.join((x[0], str(x[1]))))
df = df.replace({'':np.nan, None:np.nan})
print (df)
     Musician_0    Musician_1   Genre_0 Genre_1      Country_0       Country_1
0           NaN           NaN  mariachi     NaN         mexico   united states
1           NaN           NaN      jazz     rap  united states             NaN
2           NaN           NaN       NaN     NaN          spain             NaN
3  jimi hendrix   john lennon      rock     NaN            NaN             NaN
4        spirit           NaN       NaN     NaN  united states             NaN
5           NaN           NaN     latin     NaN  united states             NaN
6           NaN           NaN       NaN     NaN            NaN             NaN
7         speak           NaN       NaN     NaN         mexico   united states
```

If in `DataFrames` are another columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['', 'mariachi', 'mexico, united states',5],
                   ['', 'jazz, rap', 'united states',8],
                   ['', '', 'spain',8],
                   ['jimi hendrix, john lennon', 'rock', '',1],
                   ['spirit', '', 'united states',7],
                   ['', 'latin', 'united states',1],
                   ['', '', '',0],
                   ['speak', '', 'mexico, united states',3]], 
                   columns=['Musician', 'Genre', 'Country', 'Val'])
print (df)
                    Musician      Genre                Country  Val
0                              mariachi  mexico, united states    5
1                             jazz, rap          united states    8
2                                                        spain    8
3  jimi hendrix, john lennon       rock                           1
4                     spirit                     united states    7
5                                 latin          united states    1
6                                                                 0
7                      speak             mexico, united states    3
```

last you can `concat` columns, which are not splitted:

```
cols = ['Musician','Genre','Country']
df1 = pd.concat([df[x].str.split(',', expand=True) for x in cols], axis=1, keys=df.columns)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: '_'.join((x[0], str(x[1]))))
df1 = df1.replace({'':np.nan, None:np.nan})
print (df1)
     Musician_0    Musician_1   Genre_0 Genre_1      Country_0       Country_1
0           NaN           NaN  mariachi     NaN         mexico   united states
1           NaN           NaN      jazz     rap  united states             NaN
2           NaN           NaN       NaN     NaN          spain             NaN
3  jimi hendrix   john lennon      rock     NaN            NaN             NaN
4        spirit           NaN       NaN     NaN  united states             NaN
5           NaN           NaN     latin     NaN  united states             NaN
6           NaN           NaN       NaN     NaN            NaN             NaN
7         speak           NaN       NaN     NaN         mexico   united states
```

---

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1, df.drop(cols, axis=1)],axis=1)
print (df2)
     Musician_0    Musician_1   Genre_0 Genre_1      Country_0  \
0           NaN           NaN  mariachi     NaN         mexico   
1           NaN           NaN      jazz     rap  united states   
2           NaN           NaN       NaN     NaN          spain   
3  jimi hendrix   john lennon      rock     NaN            NaN   
4        spirit           NaN       NaN     NaN  united states   
5           NaN           NaN     latin     NaN  united states   
6           NaN           NaN       NaN     NaN            NaN   
7         speak           NaN       NaN     NaN         mexico   

        Country_1  Val  
0   united states    5  
1             NaN    8  
2             NaN    8  
3             NaN    1  
4             NaN    7  
5             NaN    1  
6             NaN    0  
7   united states    3
```

Comment: Thanks! This code works fine. I forgot to mention however that there are other columns which are not meant to be separated. How would one specify the columns to be processed in this case?

Comment: Restricting to Columns does not work for me this way, if I only specify those I need to be splitted all other columns get messed up. Using the same df with one more column for testing purposes does not work…

Comment: Do you find problem?

Comment: I add solution if more columns in `DataFrame`, please check it.

Comment: I’m trying to reproduce this with my data frame, your example works fine. In my case the other columns are mostly text data as well and columns still get get messed up.

Comment: There si problem with columns which are splitted?  Or with another unsplitted columns?

Comment: The first column of the Dataframe (Name `Author`, containing names) gets splitted and the spltted `Country` Columns are titled wrongly

Comment: Hmmm, I think there is problem some country name have `,` like `mexico, united, states`.. :( and then it causes mess :(

Comment: Thanks for your great help! I’ll look into my dataframe and your solution and try to work out what the problem was and then will comment here.